# iOS 8 today widget notificationCenterVibrancyEffect in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ios8, ios8-today-widget

When designing a today extension (widget) for the iOS 8 notification center with Interface Builder you can drag a `Visual Effect Views with Blur and Vibrancy` to your storyboard. To match the vibrancy effect of the notification center you should use the

```
+ (UIVibrancyEffect *)notificationCenterVibrancyEffect;
```

method of the `UIVibrancyEffect (NotificationCenter)` category.
I know how to do that in code, but when I use the view in Interface Builder I can't set a different `UIVibrancyEffect`.

Setting the effect in code after creation in Interface Builder is not possible, as the `effect` property  of `UIVisualEffectView` is readonly.

Is it possible in Xcode 6 to set that effect in Interface Builder?

Comment: One possibility would be to create a `UIVisualEffectView` subclass, override the initializer and set that as the class of the object in Interface Builder, I guess ... But there needs to be a better way?

Comment: Subclassing was not work, only `[CustomVisualEffectView initWithCoder]` is called, however it could not be overridden because of layout constraints things and some properties from interface builder.